# Map Child Elemenr of the data which is being recieved from the mongodb

Tags: reactjs

How do I map the child element of the data that is being received from the mongodb database? I'm not able to find any solution I tried the below code, but it's not working.

Structure of the data:

```
{
  data: {
    name: "xyz",
    price: "abc",
    model: "abv123",
    warrenty: "1 years",
    productDetails: {
      _id: "a67asd57d5f423",
      name: "Apple",
      model: "s7"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to map product details so that I can display in the list all the datas in sequence.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productData: [],
      orderData: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/product")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(product1 => this.setState({ productData: product1 }));

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/order")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(order1 => this.setState({ orderData: order1 }));
  }

  render() {
    const productItems = this.state.productData.map(productData => (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
        <p style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>Name: {productData.name}</p>
        <p style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>Price: {productData.price}</p>
        <p style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>Model Number: {productData.modelno}</p>
        <p style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>Warranty: {productData.warranty}</p>
        <p style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>Entry Date: {productData.entrydate}</p>
        <br />
      </div>
    ));

    const orderItems = this.state.orderData.map(orderData => (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
        <p style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>
          Customer Name: {orderData.customername}
        </p>
        <p style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>Quantity: {orderData.quantity}</p>
        <p style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>Phone Number: {orderData.phoneno}</p>
        <p style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>
          Product Details: <br /> a) Name: {orderData.productdetail}
          {/* This Product detail is a child element how do i Map it */}
          <br /> b)Price:1,00,000{" "}
        </p>
        <br />
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: "5%" }}>
        <h3 className="text-center">List</h3>
        <hr />
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-6">
            <h4 style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Product Details</h4>
            {productItems}
          </div>
          <div className="col-6">
            <h4 style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Order Details</h4>
            {orderItems}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

Comment: If you add `catch` to both your network requests, do you get an error in the console? It might be that the network requests are failing.

Comment: im looking to map the child element productdetails

Comment: Yes, I get that, but maybe the reason for it not working is that your network requests are failing.

Comment: Actually i'm really new to to react and i dont know that much. i think my codes are not correct can you help me with that.